# Flask nosetests - unable to connect to test db

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a simple Flask web application for fun and I wanted to use nosetests. I'm stuck at how to use Flask-SQLAlchemy to connect to an in-memory test database in my tests file. When I run my tests - Flask connects to my main app's database and what is more, fails to clean it up after each test. Here's my tests code:

```
import nose
from nose.tools import *
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from app import site, db

from app.models import Post


class TestApp(object):
    def setUp(self):
        site.config['TESTING'] = True
        site.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
        self.test_app = site.test_client()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        # db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_posts_index(self):
        db.session.add(Post('title', 'body'))
        db.session.add(Post('title2', 'body'))

        db.session.commit() # this writes to production db ie app.db file 
                            # instead of sqlite://
        rv = self.test_app.get('/posts')
        d = pq(rv.data)
        print len(d('h1'))
        assert len(d('h1')) == 2
```

And here's my `app/__init__.py` code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from app import config

site = Flask(__name__)

site.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config.db_uri
db = SQLAlchemy(site)
site.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'


from app import db_setup
db_setup.create_db()

import controllers, models
```

The db_setup.create_db() in `app/__init__.py` function looks simply like this:

```
from app import db
from app.models import Post
def create_db():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
```

I tried instantiating the application and database in the tests file, but then my models don't work because they `from app import db`, where db is the production db object. I also sprinkled a few print statements in the test case like `print db` and they print out something like `<SQLAlchemy engine sqlite://>`, but it still writes to the production db anyways.

I'd really appreciate any tips on how to get around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something about the environment to determine whether the app starts in a testing or live mode?

```
if 'testing' in os.environ:
    site.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
else:
    site.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config.db_uri
```

There are so many ways to skin this particular cat. If you don't like the idea of having `if` blocks littering your code you can import your settings from an entirely separate module based on whether the app is started in testing or live mode.

Comment: I do something like this, where in the very root of my program I have my configuration loaded from one of a number of configuration files (see [configuring with files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuring-from-files)) with an environment variable controlling which configuration is loaded before the app starts up. Also useful for live versus staging versus development configurations. See also [configuration best practices](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuration-best-practices), which talks about unit testing.

Comment: @MarkHildreth, aychedee - Thanks a lot for these ideas and tips. I was able to find the bug on my own (it was related to imports and such), but I will restructure my project to make use of configuration files as you outlined. Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem, it's related to me initiating a connection to the database in my `__init__.py` file, which I shouldn't do.

The culprit was the

```
from app import db_setup
db_setup.create_db()
```

code. Essentially, every time I did an `from app import db`, I think that `app` gets instantiated, it calls `db_setup.create_db()`, which creates the tables using the production config. From there on, despite trying to set the flask app config `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to an in memory database, the db object would continue to use the database instantiated in the `__init__.py` file.

All I have to do is call `create_all()` from the environment my will run in at that time. Hope this helps anyone how might run into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I didn't use a db.create_all() type statement in my **init**.py file at all.

In the end, the only way I could around the issue was to use

```
def setUp(self):
    with app.app_context():
                db.create_all()
```